# WPF - Binding a color resource to the data object within a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

I have a `DataTemplate` and a `SolidColorBrush` in the `DataTemplate.Resources` section.
I want to bind the color to a property of the same data object that the `DataTemplate` itself is bound to.
However, this does not work. The brush is ignored. Why?

Here is the simplified code:

```
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:MyData}" x:Name="dtData">
            <DataTemplate.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="bg" Color="{Binding Path=Color, Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}" />
            </DataTemplate.Resources>
            <Border CornerRadius="15"
                    Background="{StaticResource bg}"
                    Margin="0"
                    Opacity="0.5"
                    Focusable="True">
        </DataTemplate>
```

I understand I could set this directly also but I need the color to be a resource.

Comment: You do not need a SolidColorBrush resource for this. Just Bind Background="{Binding Path=Color, Converter=colorConverter}"

Comment: I understand that, but I still want the color to be a resource because I need to set the opacity of the background color. AFAIK the opacity can only be set there without affecting the opacity of the entire Border!

Answer (score 1):

"Works on My Machine" :) I have one theory. You binding is working, you border has no content so it's only consist of a border itself, but you setting background property not the BorderBrush, so actualy you background has no area, also you don't set BorderThickness so actually you have border with 0 width and 0 height. So set BorderThickness, Width or Height.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can simplify with below.

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:MyData}" x:Name="dtData">
        <Border CornerRadius="15"
                Background="{Binding Path=Color, Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}"
                Margin="0"
                Opacity="0.5"
                Focusable="True">
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I understand this is simpler, but as I commented above I have to set the background color's opacity. AFAIK the opacity can only be set there without affecting the opacity of the entire Border (meaning elements inside it)!